# Oracle: regexp for a complicated case

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I have a table, and one of the columns contains a string with items separated by semicolons(;)

I want to selectively transfer the data to a new table based on the pattern of the String.

For example, it may look like

> 16;;14;30;24;11;13;14;14;10;13;18;15;18;24;13/18;11;;23;12;;19;10;;11;26;;;42;26;38/39;12;;;;;;;11;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

or

> 11;;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;11;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

I don't care about what's between the semicolons, but I care about which positions contain items. For example, if I only want the 1st, 3rd, 4th position to contain items, I would allow the following...

> 32;;14;18/12;;;;;;;;; or 32;;14;18/12;;;;55;;;;11;;;;;;;

This one down below is not okay because the 3rd position does not hold any value.

> 32;;;18/12;;;;;;;;;

If regexp works for this, then I can use `merge into` to move the desired records to the target table. If this cannot be done, I'll have to process each record in Java, and selectively insert the records to the new table.

source table:

```
id | StringValue | count
```

target table:

```
id | StringValue | count
```

The sql that I have in mind:

```
merge into you_target_table tt
using ( select StringValue, count
        from source_table where REGEXP_LIKE ( StringValue, 'some pattern')
      ) st
on ( st.StringValue = tt.StringValue and st.count=tt.count )
when not matched then
   insert (id, StringValue , count) 
   values (someseq.nextval, st.value1, st.count)
when matched then
   update
   set tt.count = tt.count + st.count;
```

Also I'm certain that all StringValue in source table is unique, so what's after `when matched then` is not important, but due to the syntax, I think I must have something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For each position you want a value put `[^;]+;`, that matches any character, that is not `;` and occurs at least one time followed by a `;`. If you don't care for a position put `[^;]*;`. That's almost similar to the first one but the characters, that are before the `;` may also be none. Anchor the whole thing to the beginning with `^`.

So for your 1st, 3rd and 4th position example you'd get:

```
^[^;]+;[^;]*;[^;]+;[^;]+;
```

In a query that'd look like:

```
SELECT *
       FROM elbat
       WHERE regexp_like(nmuloc, '^[^;]+;[^;]*;[^;]+;[^;]+;');
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6d928f51dd5c94cd3786e4f35d45094c)

It may be further improved by putting the sub expressions in a group, that is, put parenthesis around them, and use quantors -- a number in curly braces after the group. For example `([^;]+;){2}` would match two positions that are not empty. Your example would get shorten to:

```
^[^;]+;[^;]*;([^;]+;){2}
```

Answer (score 0):

While [@stiky bit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9661424/sticky-bit) answer is totally correct there is another similar but perhaps more readable solution:

```
SELECT *
   FROM elbat
   WHERE regexp_substr(nmuloc, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 1, '', 1) is not null
   AND   regexp_substr(nmuloc, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 3, '', 1) is not null
   AND   regexp_substr(nmuloc, '(.*?)(;|$)', 1, 4, '', 1) is not null;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a799c951c02b77db35bc5475c8555fb3)

Pros:

- clearly states position number that should not be null
- has universal pattern for any condition, so no need in changing regex
- can use any regex as delimiter, not only single character
- actually extracts item, so you can further test it with any function

Cons:

- rather verbose
- n times slower, where n is condition count
- even more slower (up to 2 times) cause of backtracking on each non-delimiter symbol

However in my experience this efficiency difference is minor if query is not run against billions of rows. And even then disk reading would consume most of the time.

How it's made:

- (.*?)(;|$) - lazily searches for any character sequence (possibly zero-length) ended with delimiter or end of string
- 1 - position to start search. 1 is default. Needed only to get to the next parameter
- 1, 3 or 4 - occurrence or pattern
- '' - match_parameter. Can be used for setting up matching mode, but here also only to get to the last parameter
- 1 - sub-expression number makes regexp_substr return only first capturing group. That is (.*?) i.e. item itself without delimiter.